# Should these comments be flagged?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I see someone asking if XY thing is possible to make in XY language,  or how is it possible etc.

And these questions don't include any code, with reason, because the person who's asking doesn't know how  to make this, so he has no code, and that's why he's asking this.

I understand that this page is not a "code service"
 But still..

Yet, most of the time under such questions, I see the comment " show your code"

So the thing is: should these comments under similar questions be flagged, when these questions are obviously not about a not working code?

Comment: *Is it possible* -> Yes *How is it possible* -> write a program. I leave such comments to understand where the OP is stuck. Did they already have Python up and running? If not, they need a tutorial not an answer to a broad question. Did they fiddle with a framework or library already? That could be relevant starting point. Most comments I see (maybe they are dense, I give you that) are meant to figure out where you need to pick-up on the knowledge the  OP is lacking. The OP is not helped if I answer with a LINQ one-liner when they struggle with compiling an hello world example.

Comment: That said: those comments can be flagged once the post is edited into shape and served their goal. Keep in mind that you might need a custom reason to explain the advice has been attended to so the comment is no longer needed. If you want to to know if you flag those  as rude or abusive my answer would be no but in the current climate you're free to try your luck.

Comment: Maybe I should have started with this: Why do you feel removing those comments is a better way to have a useful answer for the OP and future visitors? What is it that makes these comments contra-productive, so much they need flagging? If they give a bad taste somehow I would be very keen to learn why that is and how I can improve my comments so both my goal (possible write a good answer to a clear question) and yours are met.

Comment: It is an entire category of questions, fits "If only my *foo* can do *bar* then all my problems are solved".  And of course it can't bar, not by a very long shot.  A commenter might try to earn a Purple Heart for trying to stop the questioner from making this mistake, but he'd be better off with an instant DV and/or a "unclear what you are asking" close vote.  Flagging such a valiant attempt at being helpful, meh, you gotta hate a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, robotic comments "what have you tried / show your code / SO is not a code writing service" are routinely added to posts where they are not needed. A question like "how to find if a string contains a given substring in R" needs no code or further information, it's already perfectly clear and answerable.

If a comment is not needed, flag it as "no longer needed". But keep in mind that nearly all those flags require manual review by a diamond moderator, and there are not so many of those. Stick to sporadic flags instead of going on a site-wide flag campaign.